# Why does my armature still not move my mesh?

Tags: armature, bones

I'm brand new to this so go easy on me. I'm using Blender 3.1 with the cats extension and despite parenting, weight painting(some of it) and assigning vertex groups, the mesh still doesn't move with the armature when moved in pose mode despite following fine in object mode. It may be because the number of vertexes is so low or that the mesh is not continuous but I have no idea.
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I have attempted to upload the file on pasteall but it claims that the file is not a .blend file. Are there any other ways to share a .blend file?

Comment: use wetransfer, send it to yourself and share the link here  ;)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! https://we.tl/t-o3zxQEnoXl

Answer (score 0):

In the *Armature* modifier, remove the selected vertex group (*Body*). But anyway there are some vertex groups missing in the mesh, for example the fingers, so the armature won't be able to control it correctly. So maybe remove the *Armature* modifier, join the head object to the rest of the body, shift select the armature, parent *With Empty Groups*, then switch the character to *Edit* mode, select each part and assign it to the good vertex group (select the vertices with <kbd>L</kbd> then go into the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups*, select the group in the list and click on *Assign*). It should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much!